# Google формы. Можно ли создать свою форму

Tags: google-docs, html

Итак [формы Google](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/google/38716/) не очень красивы и удобны.Есть ли возможность сделать свою HTML страничку с формой и посылать результат некому Google скрипту ? тогда можно было бы распологать варианты комфортней

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашёл возможное решение - тут с проверкой даже на пустые поля

http://www.morningcopy.com.au/tutorials/google-forms-and-jquery-validation/

Answer (score 0):

**Google api** если для данного сервиса он есть. Если нет то никак.